Are .bbclass files Python? If not, what are they?
I'm using Yocto Dunfell, but I need SBOM generation that is found in Yocto 4. I found someone who did a backport in Dunfell and did the same. However, I have issues during the build process.
One of the modifications is in package.bbclass. In my investigation on why it didn't work, I've reverted the entire file to what it was an tried to modify bit by bit until it no longer works. However, any modification I'm doing in this file causes an error down the line, even adding a comment.
What is happening? Aren't bbclass files mostly Python code?

Does this answer your question? Need clarification regarding when to use bb/inc file in Yocto
